# Strategies for Enhancing Algorithm Efficiency?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have this task:

Mother Anna opened a package of candies, which she wants to distribute to her children as a reward. So that they are not
clashes between them, so of course the one who finished in a better place in the competition cannot get less
candies than the one that ended up in a worse place. How many ways can Anna divide C candies among D children?

The task:
For the given numbers D and C, find the number of possible distributions of candies.

Entrance:
In the first line of the file there is a number Q indicating the number of sets.
There are Q rows with a pair of numbers D and C.

- 1 ≤ Q ≤ 1000
- 1 ≤ D ≤ 100
- 1 ≤ C ≤ 5,000

Output:
The output of the program is the result for each set modulo (2^30)-1 on a separate line.

Example
Input:

```
3
1 10
2 4
3 8
```

Output:

```
1
3
10
```

I made this code and it works, but when i have 1000 inputs i get **Timelimit ** in evaluator, can you help me make code that will work faster?

```
def generate_combinations(d, c, current_combination=None, combinations=None):
    if current_combination is None:
        current_combination = []

    if combinations is None:
        combinations = []

    if d == 0:
        if c == 0:
            if all(current_combination[i] <= current_combination[i + 1] for i in range(len(current_combination) - 1)):
                
                combinations.append(list(current_combination))
        return

    for i in range(c + 1):
        generate_combinations(d - 1, c - i, current_combination + [i], combinations)

    return combinations

c = 8  
d = 3 

pocet = int(input())
for i in range(pocet):
    d, c = map(int, input().split())
    print(len(generate_combinations(d, c)))
```

I also have version using dynamic programming

```
def dynamic_programming(d, c):
    dp = [[0] * (c + 1) for _ in range(d + 1)]
    dp[0][0] = 1

    for i in range(1, d + 1):
        for j in range(c + 1):
            dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j]
            if j >= i:
                dp[i][j] += dp[i][j - i]
            dp[i][j] %= (2 ** 30 - 1)
    b = dp[d][c]
    return dp[d][c]

q = int(input().strip())

for i in range(q):
    d, c = map(int, input().split())
    print(dynamic_programming(d, c))
```

For better understending here is the example if we want to divide 8 candies among 3 children we have 21 possibilities:

```
[0, 0, 8]
[0, 1, 7]
[0, 2, 6]
[0, 3, 5]
[0, 4, 4]
[0, 5, 3]
[0, 6, 2]
[0, 7, 1]
[0, 8, 0]
[1, 0, 7]
[1, 1, 6]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 5, 2]
[1, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 0]
[2, 0, 6]
[2, 1, 5]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 3]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 5, 1]
[2, 6, 0]
[3, 0, 5]
[3, 1, 4]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 4, 1]
[3, 5, 0]
[4, 0, 4]
[4, 1, 3]
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 3, 1]
[4, 4, 0]
[5, 0, 3]
[5, 1, 2]
[5, 2, 1]
[5, 3, 0]
[6, 0, 2]
[6, 1, 1]
[6, 2, 0]
[7, 0, 1]
[7, 1, 0]
[8, 0, 0]
```

And there is only 10 possibilities that fit for this task:

```
[0, 0, 8]
[0, 1, 7]
[0, 2, 6]
[0, 3, 5]
[0, 4, 4]
[1, 1, 6]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I understand that one allocation would be for Anna to give all the candies to the child that did the best in the competition. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that each assignment of candies is an [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partition) of `n` candies into `k` parts. Also note that for each partition of `n` candies, there is a single unique assignment candies to children that is valid (e.g. for `n=7` the partition `3 3 1` can only be mapped to children in one way, `[0, 3, 3]`, anything else would be invalid).

With this, we just need to count the number of k-partitions of `n`, which has a nice recursive formula:

```
p(0, 0) = 1
p(n, k) = 0  if n <= 0 or k <= 0
p(n, k) = p(n - k, k) + p(n - 1, k - 1)
```

Now, we need to be careful-  this formula counts non-empty partitions, but we allow giving a child `0` candies. We could alter the recurrence relation, but there's a simpler approach; if we just add `1` additional candy per each child at the start, and then imagine we just remove that one candy from their part afterwards, it'll be just as if we allowed empty partitions.

Implemented in python:

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def count_parts(candies, children):
    if candies == children == 0:
        return 1
    if candies <= 0 or children <= 0:
        return 0
    return count_parts(candies - children, children) + count_parts(candies - 1, children - 1)
```

Example usage:

```py
test_cases = [(10, 1), (4, 2), (8, 3)]
for candies, children in test_cases:
    print(count_parts(candies + children, children))
```

Output:

```
1
3
10
```

This will be `O(C*D)` time and space, A bottom-up dynamic programming solution would have the same time complexity but would be slightly faster in practice and could be made to have a linear (in terms of `C`) space complexity.

The details are escaping me at the moment, but I believe there's also an early-exit shortcut calculation for `p(2*k, k)` that could be used for further speedup as well.

Comment: Well, today I learned a lot. Probably most usefully the `@cache` decorator but the integer partition is interesting too, especially your workaround for the empty partitions. This code runs about 10x faster than mine.

Comment: Your solution works correctly, but unfortunately the evaluator still shows Timelimit, perhaps there is an even faster solution?

Comment: @Oerlikon I'll implement the DP solution later today and update my answer, it should be far faster.  Would using `numpy` for faster (vectorized) array operations be allowed for your solution?

Comment: I'm so sorry but I can't answer if using numpy is allowed, but now I know that evaluator that check my code, use Python 3.7 and the problem is also that I can't use @cache because it doesn't exist in Python 3.7

Comment: @Oerlikon ah, then replace `@cache` with `@lru_cache(maxsize=4096)` (imported from the same `functools` package).  The caching is crucial to performance, without it the function runs in exponential time, which explains why it timed out, if you removed the decorator.

Comment: I have replaced @cache with @lru_cache(maxsize=4096) but still get Timelimit

Comment: @Oerlikon you should try with `maxsize=None`; for the largest possible values of `C` and `D` (5000,100) there are 480000 entries in the cache. On my computer `maxsize=None` brings the runtime down to 0.2 seconds for those parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count the number of valid combinations, you can use this code which allocates candies to the "best" child, then allocates the balance of the candies to the other children recursively. This code should operate more efficiently than yours as it *only* looks at potentially valid combinations, and it caches previously seen results:

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def distribute_candies(C, Q, last_C = None):
    if C == 0:
        # can only distribute 0 as [0] * Q
        return 1
    if Q == 1:
        # they get them all
        return 1
    # maximum number of candies the "best" person can have is C, 
    # or as many as the last person had if that is less
    # minimum number (which still allows distribution) is (C + Q - 1) // Q
    maxc = min(C, last_C if last_C else C)
    minc = (C + Q - 1) // Q
    valid = 0
    for c in range(maxc, minc-1, -1):
        valid += distribute_candies(C - c, Q - 1, c)
    return valid

distribute_candies(4, 2)
# 3
distribute_candies(8, 3)
# 10
```

If you're interested in the actual combinations, you can use this code (and just take `len` of the return to get the number of them) although you should note this runs out of memory quickly for large inputs due to the number of combinations:

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def distribute_candies(C, Q, last_C = None):
    if Q == 1:
        # they get them all
        return [[C]]
    # maximum number of candies the "best" person can have is C, 
    # or as many as the last person had if that is less
    # minimum number (which still allows distribution) is (C + Q - 1) // Q
    maxc = min(C, last_C if last_C else C)
    minc = (C + Q - 1) // Q
    dist_C = []
    for c in range(maxc, minc-1, -1):
        dist_C += [l + [c] for l in distribute_candies(C - c, Q - 1, c)]
    return dist_C

distribute_candies(4, 2)
# [[0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 2]]
distribute_candies(8, 3)
# [[0, 0, 8], [0, 1, 7], [0, 2, 6], [1, 1, 6], [0, 3, 5], [1, 2, 5], [0, 4, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: My intuition tells me that we should be able to come up with a closed-form expression for the number of combinations (i.e., no iteration required). You may wish to put some thought to that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland see the other answer...